# How to use DirectoryInfo to populate a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I am currently trying to look through a directory to find .jpg files and display the findings in a listbox. Then when I have done that I would like to select an image and have it displayed in a picturebox.

This is the code I have:

```
    private void Form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filepath = "F:\\Apps Development\\Coursework\\3_Coursework\\3_Coursework\\bin\\Debug\\Pics";
        DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);
        FileInfo[] images = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.jpg");
        foreach (FileInfo image in images) 
        {  
            lstImages.Items.Add(image.Name);
        }
    }

    private void lstImages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filepath = "F:\\Apps Development\\Coursework\\3_Coursework\\3_Coursework\\bin\\Debug\\Pics";
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = filepath + lstImages.SelectedItem.ToString();
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
    }
```

This seems to look as though it should work. But it doesn't populate the list with what I would like. Any ideas?

Comment: Ru it in the debugger and make sure `GetFiles` is returning a non-empty array.

Comment: Just use your debugger :\ Is anything actually getting returned by `GetFiles`? Do you even have anything in that directory that's jpg?

Comment: filepath + @"\" + lstImages.SelectedItem.ToString(); OR filepath = "F:\\Apps Development\\Coursework\\3_Coursework\\3_Coursework\\bin\\Debug\\Pics\\";

Comment: all the files in that directory are .jpg. I have tested this code in a console application with a: Console.WriteLine(image.Name); and this turns back the filenames

Comment: ?! I am communicating so badly a so simple idea? A SLASH IS MISSING, this is the path you are considering: F:\Apps Development\Coursework\3_Coursework\3_Coursework\bin\Debug\Picspic1.jpg instead of: F:\Apps Development\Coursework\3_Coursework\3_Coursework\bin\Debug\Pics\pic1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
//load all image here
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //set your directory
    DirectoryInfo myDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\MyImages");
    //set file type
    FileInfo[] allFiles = myDirectory.GetFiles("*.jpg");
    //loop through all files with that file type and add it to listBox
    foreach (FileInfo file in allFiles)
    {
            listBox1.Items.Add(file);
    }
}

//bind clicked image with picturebox
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Make selected item an image object
    Image clickedImage = Image.FromFile(@"E:\MyImages\" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    pictureBox1.Image = clickedImage;
    pictureBox1.Height = clickedImage.Height;
    pictureBox1.Width = clickedImage.Width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your snippet on my machine and it works fine (i modified the path).

```
        string filepath = @"c:\temp";
   DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);
   FileInfo[] images = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.*");
   var list = new List<string>();
   foreach (FileInfo image in images) 
   {  
        list.Add(image.Name);      

   }
   lstImages.DataSource = list;
```

So I think it has to do with how you are passing in the directory to your constructor. Recommend you use the @"blahblah" to denote string literals like I did above.

Comment: Thanks tom.. but that was my original attempt, then someone mentioned to try a variable for the path. I will give it another shot and get back to you

Comment: He is missing a slash!!! in pictureBox1.ImageLocation. He is writing the file name right after the dir name without a slash in between!!! Is nobody reading the comments, here or what?

Comment: Nope. Just done what you said and it gave the same result it always has :/

Comment: @MarkLockhart you are kidding me, don't you?

Comment: I haven't actually got that far varocarbas.. I have changed that part to work. but I can't get passed listing the items first

Comment: @MarkLockhart Ok, Ok... I thought that my English became suddenly understandable. I don't know what might be the problem, but this path issue has to be fixed no matter what.

Comment: Ah - you have to refresh the DataSource of the listbox. So try this:   string filepath = @"c:\temp";
   DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);
   FileInfo[] images = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.*");
   var list = new List<string>();
   foreach (FileInfo image in images) 
   {  
  list.Add(image.Name);      

   }
   lstImages.DataSource = list;

Answer (score 0):

You should make the path variable a member of the class. This way you can be sure that both methods use the same path. But this is not the cause of your problem. It is the missing slash when you compose the image location (as @varocarbas already stated in a comment).

To avoid such problems you should use the static [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Populating the list can also be done more elegant using LINQ:

```
string filepath = @"F:\Apps Development\Coursework\3_Coursework\3_Coursework\bin\Debug\Pics";

private void Form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstImages.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(filepath, "*.jpg")
                                      .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).ToArray());
}

private void lstImages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = Path.Combine(filepath, lstImages.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```